# Custom AmazonS3Client for ResourceLoader with Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud

As Spring Cloud AWS won't provide a configuration variable to use a custom endpoint (I'm currently using DigitalOcean Spaces as my S3 service) I registered an AmazonS3 bean in my configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceLoaderConfiguration {

  private @Value("${cloud.aws.endpoint}") String endpoint;

  @Bean
  public AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
        RegionProvider regionProvider) {

    EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(
            endpoint, regionProvider.getRegion().getName());

    return (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                                .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
                                .build();
  }
```

But for some reason this bean won't be taken into account for the resource loader, so when I try to get an object like this:

```
resourceLoader.getResource("s3://" + bucket + "/" + key);
```

I get an exception:

```
AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;
```

Is there a way to bind my custom client implementation with the resource loader?

Also, when I try to autowire an AmazonS3Client bean I get an error because there are 2 instances found:

```
Field s3Client in com.webapp.services.storage.S3StorageService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- amazonS3Client: defined by method 'amazonS3Client' in class path resource [com/webapp/config/ResourceLoaderConfiguration.class]
- amazonS3: defined in null
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this @joaquin  ? I cannot use Resourceloader when using localstack.

Comment: hi @ravikant! I used a named bean to differenciate between instances (I think)

Comment: Actually with Spring cloud AWS 2.3 they introduced a property: cloud.aws.s3.endpoint=http://localhost:4566 which can actually help in doing that. Release notes: https://spring.io/blog/2021/03/17/spring-cloud-aws-2-3-is-now-available.

But this requires me to add an entry in the /etc/hosts file: 
127.0.0.1        bucketname.localhost

Comment: Can you tell me which version of spring-cloud-aws you were using ?

Comment: I'm using the spring boot starter parent version 2.3.3.RELEASE